# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected embedding_37 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (90, 1)

Tags: python, nlp

I have trained a model for CNN and I am getting the error on the Embedding layer and I use my pre trained embedding to classification

my code

```
embed_size = 300
max_features = 100000
maxlen = 254
num_filters = 100
nb_words = min(max_features , len(word_index)) + 1
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(nb_words, embed_size, trainable=False))
model.add(Conv1D(num_filters, 7, activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
model.add(Conv1D(num_filters, 7, activation='relu', padding='same'))
```

Model Summary

```
Model: "sequential_47"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_38 (Embedding)     (None, None, 300)         537900    
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_39 (Conv1D)           (None, None, 100)         210100    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_19 (MaxPooling (None, None, 100)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_40 (Conv1D)           (None, None, 100)         70100     
=================================================================
Total params: 818,100
Trainable params: 280,200
Non-trainable params: 537,900
_________________________________________________________________
```

I tried to train model

```
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.01, patience=4, verbose=1)
callbacks_list = [early_stopping]
model.fit(train_X, y_train, batch_size=1000, epochs=10, verbose=1,
         callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected embedding_37 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (90, 1)
```

train_X.shape

```
(90, 352)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you